# Conditions for matrix operator to preserve complex symmetry on DFT vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, symmetry

Suppose there is a DFT vector $\mathbf{X}$ (complex vector) with length N, which presents complex conjugate symmetry around its middle point, i.e., $X(1) = X(N-1)^*$, $X(2) = X(N - 2)^*$ and so forth. X(0) and X(N/2) are the DC and Nyquist frequency respectively, therefore are real numbers. The remaining elements are complex.

Now, suppose there is a matrix $\mathbf{T}$, with size $N \times N$, which multiplies vector X.

\begin{align}
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{T}\mathbf{X}
\end{align}

The question is:

In what conditions, for matrix $\mathbf{T}$, the complex conjugte symmetry around the middle point of the resulting vector $\mathbf{Y}$ is preserved?